# Converting multiple audio files in different subdirectories using ffmpeg

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert multiple .mp3 files stored in different folders to .wav file using ffmpeg. The .wav files will be stored in the folder where the .mp3 file is located

```
import os
folder = r'D:\S2ST_DataCollection-main\public\recordings' ##### root folder


count = 0
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in files:
        filename_without_extension, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if extension == '.mp3':       ######## get all the mp3 files
            count +=1
            os.system(r"C:\Users\amart\Downloads\Compressed\S2ST_DataCollection-main\public\music.bat") ###### use the mp3 to wav conversion stored as batch file
```

My music.bat file

```
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vn -c:a pcm_s16le  -ar 44100 "%%~na.wav"
```

Note: I have used pydub but it is not working

If i use the batch command only in a folder it is working fine but my .mp3 files are located in multiple folder

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could recursively search the folders and append the absolute path of each file to a list, then loop through the list and pass the values to pydub.

Comment: you could simplify your code by removing extension = os.path.splitext(filename) and if extension == '.mp3' by and using if filename.endswith('.mp3').